# How to put strings of various length in a pointer, say char *output[100]

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, char

I want to put strings of various sizes into an 2D array,represented as `char *array[size];` example for various size of strings could be :- `"Hi", "Welcome";`.

This should fit into the above given array: If the array is given in this format: `char array[][]` I could do it, using the code below.:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char array[][100];

int main()
{    
    char buf[10];

    sprintf(buf,"%d", 12);
    strcpy(array[0], buf);
    sprintf(buf, "%s", "hello");
    strcpy(array[1], buf);
    printf("%s %s", array[0], array[1]);
}
```

But the same I am unable to do, If the array is given in the format `char *array[]`.

Any help will be very helpful.
Thank You.

Comment: You need to expcitly give a size for both dimensions.

Comment: sounds like you want `char *ptrsToStrings[nRows][nCols]`. Your `array[][100]` is functioning as an array of strings, since a string is already an array of `char`s.

Comment: I am sorry,but the how do I give size to the first dimension here, its char * array[size];

Comment: Your code won't compile, try `char array[2][100];` for the example given with two strings.

Comment: Here's where you might want to step away and do a bit more reading on the distinction between, vs similarities of, pointers and arrays. Maybe you think you need one of these but actually don't. But if you do want a 2D array of C 'strings' (i.e. pointers to null-terminated `char` buffers), then read my suggested declaration backwards: it's a 2D array of variables that themselves are each a pointer to the 1st `char` of each respective string.

Comment: That code does not even compile. At least you should provide compilable code.

Comment: The code compiles with a warning: sprintf_try.c:3:6: warning: "array ‘array’ assumed to have one element", and runs fine. If you want not to see that, give a size to the first dimesion.But the given code is not my question. I want the array in the format of char * array[size] only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have hard-coded the two strings anyway, you can declare a pointer array like this:

```
char *array[] = {"Hi", "Welcome"};
```

These *string literals* are read-only. A more exhaustive approach could be like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STRINGS 2
#define MAXLEN  100

int main(void)
{    
    char buf[MAXLEN];
    char *array[STRINGS];                       // array of string pointers
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<STRINGS; i++) {
        printf("Enter string %d: ", i+1);
        if (fgets(buf, MAXLEN, stdin) == NULL)
            return 0;                           // bad input
        buf [ strcspn(buf, "\r\n") ] = 0;       // remove trailing newline etc
        array[i] = malloc(strlen(buf)+1);       // only as much as needed
        if (array[i] == NULL)
            return 0;                           // bad memory allocation
        strcpy(array[i], buf);
    }

    // print the array
    for (i=0; i<STRINGS; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", array[i]);
    }

    // free the memory
    for (i=0; i<STRINGS; i++) {
        free(array[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh yes, I found the mistake.I was not doing malloc before strcpy,so I was getting segmentation fault.The declaration makes an array of pointers to strings,whose memory I must allocate.Thank You for helping me out in this :)

Answer (score 2):

There are two different kinds of data structure called a “two-dimensional array” in C.  Both, thanks to operator overloading, have rows addressed by `table[i]` and elements addressed by `table[i][j]`.

A contiguous block of memory that is logically subdivided into row-sized chunks is sometimes called a *rectangular array* (because if you laid the elements out as a table, all the rows would line up perfectly) and an array of pointers is sometimes called a *ragged array*.  If you want to use one of those, you need to allocate memory for each row yourself.  Here’s some example code that mixes both.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ROWS 100U
#define COLS 32U

char rectangular_array[ROWS][COLS] = {'\0'};
char *ragged_array[ROWS] = {NULL};

int main(void) {
  strncpy( rectangular_array[0], "hello,", COLS-1 );
  strncpy( rectangular_array[1], "world!", COLS-1 );
  /* I don't need to set the third string to "" or the final bytes to
   * '\0' explicitly because I initialized the array to zeroes.
   */

  size_t i = 0;
  while( i < ROWS && rectangular_array[i][0] ) {
    const char* const s = &rectangular_array[i][0];
    const size_t m = strlen(s)+1;
    char* const t = malloc(m);

    printf( "%s ", s );
    // Copy the contents into ragged_array.
    assert(t);
    memcpy( t, s, m );
    ragged_array[i] = t;
    ++i;
  }

  if ( i < ROWS )
    ragged_array[i] = NULL;
  /* We DO, however, need to set the termiating entry of this array to
   * NULL, because, contrary to common misconception, a pointer with all
   * bits zeroed out is not necessarily a NULL pointer, and there are
   * implementations in the real world where NULL is a different
   * special value that traps on some hardware.
   *
   * Confusingly, the standard does say that assigning the constant 0 to
   * a pointer sets it to NULL.
   */

  puts("\n");

  for ( i = 0; i < ROWS && ragged_array[i]; ++i ) {
    // Print the contents of each row of ragged_array, then free each row.
    printf( "%s ", ragged_array[i] );
    free(ragged_array[i]);
    ragged_array[i] = NULL;
  }

  puts("\n");

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I should not had missed malloc while using the ragged array. Its beautiful the way you explained. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @AshishRanjan You’re welcome.  I’ve tried to make it even prettier.